# Создание таблицы функторов

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо создать таблицу `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunctor> >`функторов, где каждый функтор может принимать различное количество аргументов.
Написав такой код

```
struct AbstractFunctor
{
virtual operator() () = 0
virtual ~AbstractFunctor() {} 
} 



struct func1: AbstractFunctor

{

double operator() (const double& val) override;

~func1() {} 

} 

struct func2: AbstractFunctor

{

int operator() (const double& val1, const double& val2) override;

~func2() {} 

}
```

Я понял, что это не будет работать, тк мы переопределяем как будто бы не ту функцию.
Как можно было бы сделать так, чтобы моя идея сработала?

Сначала подумал, что можно создать

```
virtual double operator() (const double&) =0;
```

Но быстро отдернул себя от этой мысли, тк в каждом наследнике нужно будет переопределить этот метод
Может быть есть способ перегрузить переопределенный метод?

Comment: Калькулятор пишете? :) Меня всегда смущает в этой постановке вот что: сделали. Получили функтор. Но как вы будете в него передавать аргументы? Все равно ведь придется руками писать f(a) или f(a,b,c,d)... Не проще ли передавать один аргумент — массив аргументов?

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. Рассказывайте зачем вам понадобилась такая таблица и как ее потом собираетесь использовать.

Comment: @Harry, да, его. Ну, я реализовываю его через метод рекурсивного спуска. Для тригонометрических функций требуется 1 аргумент. Для логарифма и возведения в степень требуется 2 аргумента. Я распределил в коде все так, что логарифм по основанию n и возведение в степень обрабатываются отдельно, но мне бы хотелось использовать все-таки такой map, да и само решение задачи впринципе интересно

Comment: Для тригонометрических да, но тогда требование *"каждый функтор может принимать различное количество аргументов"* излишне. И решение очевидно. А если у вас, ну, скажем, pow и sin. И вернулся некий функтор. Как вы вызов писать будете? Проверять, что это за функция? Тогда и `map` городить не стоило...

Comment: @user7860670, описал выше

Comment: @Harry, мне просто показалось, что для каждой тригометрической функции не стоит делать отдельную обработку и вызывать функцию через map

Comment: Да я же не против такого решения, просто указал на возникающую сложность..

Comment: @Harry, понял и согласен, что возможно с AbstractFunctor уже премудрил, но меня заинтересовало скорее уже просто решение такой задачи не только для функтора, а впринципе для любой функции у наследника, который берет разное кол-во аргументов. Мне кажется, что массив не очень подходит и может можно средствами переопределений и перегрузок решить данную проблему? Просто пока не могу понять как и можно ли впринципе

Comment: @ment, каждый раз, когда я вижу такие подходы, то вспоминаю высказывание Дейкстры -- "C++ damages the brain"

Comment: @avp Так это у тех, кто его не знает :)

Comment: @Harry, уточнить у EWD, что именно он думал об этом, к сожалению, мы уже никогда не сможем ...

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите понять как этому добиться, то в первую очередь нужно понять, что переопределенные функции должны быть того же типа, что и базовая. В принципе разного количества аргументов можно добиться также с использованием аттрибута `maybe_unused`, который даст возможность просто не использовать аргумент. Можно пользоваться функциями с переменным количеством аргументов, можно передавать в функцию контейнер, массив, или можно в не виртуальном операторе вызвать виртуальную функцию. В таком виде вопроса не понятно чего вы хотите добиваться и зачем вообше наслеование понадобилось, если можно использовать просто шаблон. Вообще использование наследования должно быть  убедительно оправдано, иначе это лишний тормоз.